# Is this writing incorrect?

Tags: calculus, differential

If we want to find $\frac{d}{dx}\cos x^2 $ then is this writing incorrect $\frac{d}{dx} \cos x^2= \frac{d}{dx^2}\cos x^2 \times \frac{d}{dx} x^2 $

Comment: Does $\cos x^2$ mean $\cos (x^2)$ or $(\cos x)^2$?

Comment: Assuming you are writing $\cos(x^2)$, this is correct, although notation like $\frac{d}{dx^2}$ is usually frowned upon.

Comment: @Henry I mean $\cos (x^2)$ here

Comment: I would at least make parentheses around the $x^2$ in the derivative (that is, $\frac{d}{d(x^2)}$), to make clear that it's not the derivative operator itself that's squared (as it would be for the second derivative, $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. That's correct. In general (chain rule):

$$\frac{d}{dt}F(g(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}g(t) \times \frac{d}{d(g(t))}F(g(t)) $$

Answer (score 1):

No. This expression is not wrong. $cos(x^2)$ is just a composite function.

Derivative of such functions can be taken by using chain rule.